# Trying to scrape XE.com into a GoogleSheets spreadsheet with importxml

Tags: google-sheets, google-sheets-formula, screen-scraping, spreadsheet

What I am trying to achieve should be fairly simple, I can do it with PowerQuery in excel but still relatively new to Google Sheets.

I am using the importxml function to import the table from this link:

https://www.xe.com/currencytables/?from=EUR&date=2020-10-31

=importxml("https://www.xe.com/currencytables/?from=EUR&date=2020-10-31", "//td")

However the result I am getting is imported all in one column and I need it in the same format as in the html table, retain the headers and have currency code in one column, currency rate in the other and then the rates in the next two.

How can I rework that importxml function to achieve that?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Use `IMPORTHTML` instead:

#### Formula:

`=IMPORTHTML("https://www.xe.com/currencytables/?from=EUR&date=2020-10-31", "table", 1)`

- This gets the 1st table in the provided URL.

#### Output:

[image: Output]

#### Reference:

- [IMPORTHTML](https://support.google.com/docs/answer/3093339?hl=en)

Comment: Haha so easy. Awesome. What if I want to scrape more than one date, i.e. more than one URL

I tried with an arrayformula but it returns only one table from one of the URLs

=ARRAYFORMULA(IMPORTHTML(Sheet1!C:C,"table", 1))

In Sheet1!C1 and below I have the list of URLs

Comment: Sorry @user15005160 but `ARRAYFORMULA` doesn't support `IMPORT` functions. You can try doing it in script instead.